# cant login to machine/aspnet error

Tags: asp.net

I published the website to IIS virtual directory, and it can't connect to sql server?!!

What is the damn problem with this?!

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

What authentication are you using?

If using Windows Authentication (SSPI/Integrated Security), then you'll need to grant database access to the ASPNET account that the ASP.NET worker process uses.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using integrated security or SSPI for SQL Authentication, you will need to add NETWORK_SERVICE as an allowed login to the DB

Comment: Russ is correct, for Windows XP it's ASPNET.  For Server 2k3 it's NETWORK_SERVICE.  I believe it's something else on 2k8, but can't remember off the top of my head.

Comment: In SQL Server go to Security and add NETWORK_SERVICE as a logon.  Then go to the particular db and go to security for that and add the new logon as a user to the db with appropriate access.

When you run your app under VS.NET (really WebDev.WebServer) it runs under your user id, which probably has db_owner permissions on the database.